# Formula Evaluation issue with using org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel package

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using apache poi 3.6 with java to read excel files.initially i started with HSSF files.So, i was implementing `org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;` package for all those functionalities.

For Example...

1)  i am using `mySheet.setForceFormulaRecalcualtion(true);` => for formula must be recalculated when workbook is opened.

2)`org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator=new FormulaEvaluator(mySheet, myWorkBook);`

`formulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);`=> to evaluate the formula and save the result of the formula.

But I want to use these functionalities for both HSSF(.xls) and XSSF(.xlsx) formatted files.so, now I am implementing `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel` package to represent both .xls and .xlsx files.

But I am able to do all those function that has already done in HSSF. But I can't do the above said 2 functionalities using this `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel` package..

Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found there is a Class in org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator; we can solve the above problem using this by following way:

FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = myWorkBook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
formulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);

I think it would be helpful to you...